# Merge git branches in PowerShell from Azure Pipelines

Tags: git, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am working on Azure pipelines, running on Windows Self-hosted agents.

We have a yaml pipeline that gets triggered manually, build the project, create an artifact and deploy to our staging environment.

Currently it works, it gets the develop branch from github and do as mentionned.

I want to change this so the develop branch gets merged to a release branch, we reuse always the same release branch while the version gets to PROD.  In a future step, after an approval, the release branch should get merged to the master branch.
I don't know git very well, I used SourceSafe for many years.

I don't know which approach is best:

#1

```
-Download develop branch as currently
-Build and create the package and deploy
-Download release branch
-Download the develop branch over it to get the release + develop
-Push back to git
```

#2

```
-Download release branch
-Download the develop branch over it to get the release + develop
-Push back to git
-Build and create the package and deploy
```

The second approach seems best but as Azure downloads develop by default... I wanted to write a PowerShell function that does this and can be reused also to merge release to master, I ended-up writing this command line script but it doesn't work:

```
parameters:
- name: 'SourceBranch'
  default: 'develop'
  type: string
- name: 'TargetBranch'
  default: 'release'
  type: string
- name: 'Tag'
  default: ''
  type: string

- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
      script: |
        git checkout ${{parameters.TargetBranch}}
        git tag ${{parameters.Tag}}
        git push --tags

        git pull ${{parameters.SourceBranch}}
```

I tried changing the value of `SourceBranch` to `develop` or `origin\develop` but I always get :

```
fatal: 'whatever I used' does not appear to be a git repository
```

I'm not sure of my code and if my idea is good so if you could help me with some guidance, that would be very helpful.

Knowing that later on, I would reuse the script with source is release and target is master !
Thanks.

-- UPDATE 1 -----------------------
Here are the logs generated by a default step in the pipeline:

```
##[section]Starting: Checkout [myOrg]/[myProject]@develop to s
git version 2.26.2.windows.1
##[command]git config --get remote.origin.url
##[command]git clean -ffdx
##[command]git reset --hard HEAD
HEAD is now at bd75f7d [***]
##[command]git config gc.auto 0
##[command]git config --get-all http.https://github.com/[myOrg]/[myProject].extraheader
##[command]git config --get-all http.proxy
##[command]git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: basic ***" -c http.proxy="http://[***]:443" fetch --force --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin
##[command]git checkout --progress --force e99a6[***]b4bdf
Note: switching to 'e99a6[***]b4bdf'.
You are in 'detached HEAD' state...
HEAD is now at e99a6ca Update README.md
##[command]git config http.https://github.com/[myOrg]/[myProject].extraheader "AUTHORIZATION: basic ***"
##[command]git config http.proxy "http://[***]:443"
##[section]Finishing: Checkout [myOrg]/[myProject]@develop to s
```

Then, the logs created by my script :

```
git checkout release
Previous HEAD position was e99a6ca Update README.md
Switched to branch 'release'
git status
On branch release
nothing to commit, working tree clean
git tag - OECD.Glue.Contacts.API_9457
git push --tags
To https://github.com/[myOrg]/[myProject]
* [new tag]         [myProject]_9457 -> [myProject]_9457
git pull origin\develop
fatal: 'origin\develop' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I tried again but providing "only develop" or "[myOrg]/[myProject]@develop" as the source branch but I always get the same error !

-- UPDATE 2 -----------------------

As a default, the pipelines checkouts the develop branch, I tried using this to prevent this useless checkout:

```
- checkout: none
```

But got this log:

```
git status
->  On branch release
->  nothing to commit, working tree clean
git tag ${{parameters.Tag}}
git push --tags
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

Using the checkout below, removed the error, I thought it could help either my issues or anyone having this error:

```
- checkout: self
  clean: true
  persistCredentials: true
```

As suggested, I used:

```
git push
```

But I had this error:

```
-> fatal: The current branch release has no upstream branch.
```

I tried this:

```
git push --verbose --repo=release
```

Then I got:

```
Pushing to release
fatal: 'release' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

It is still blurry for me, do I really need to checkout develop first ?
Is it linked to the fact that our default branch in GitHub is always 'develop' ?

How can I tell if I am have enough access rights ? on GitHub using the same account, I can compare: "`base:release <- compare:develop`" and request a PR!
Comparing changes says there is 137 commits that were done on develop but not on release which is correct and also that these branches can be automatically merged.

Does the command: "`git push release`" means update the release branch in github from the repo staged locally on the Build Agent ?

Thanks a lot.

-- Recap -----------------------

As a recap, this project currently has three branches.

- develop is where developers are committing
- release holds the version currently on staging environments
- master holds the version currently on production environment

I wanted a script that merges develop to release and then from release to master
I have this pipeline:

```
- name: projectName
  value: '***'

stages:
  - stage: InitRelease
    jobs:
    - job: Branch
      steps:
        - checkout: self
          clean: true
          persistCredentials: true
        - template: git-branch-source-2-target.yml@templates
          parameters:
            TargetBranch: 'release'
            Tag: '${{ variables.projectName }}_${{ variables.buildId }}'
```

git-branch-source-2-target.yml:

```
parameters:
- name: 'SourceBranch'
  default: 'develop'
  type: string

- name: 'TargetBranch'
  default: 'release'
  type: string

- name: 'Tag'
  default: ''
  type: string

steps:
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
      script: |
        git checkout ${{parameters.TargetBranch}}
        git tag ${{parameters.Tag}}
        git push --tags
        git pull origin ${{parameters.SourceBranch}}
        git push --verbose --repo=${{parameters.TargetBranch}}
```

This is my output:

```
Switched to branch 'release'
To https://github.com/myOrg/myProject
 * [new tag]         myProject_9527 -> myProject_9527
From https://github.com/myOrg/myProject
 * branch            develop    -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
Pushing to release
fatal: 'release' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Does the repo have a remote set during the pipeline?

Comment: I'm confused by the terms remote, origin...  it is the first job of the pipeline, the repo is copied to the agent, I added nothing else.  Would you need a extraction of the logs ?  Thanks.

Comment: A remote is the term for another git repository. It can even be on the same machine. Origin is the default name for a remote. Usually this is created when a repo is cloned. If pushing/pulling is failing then it would seem that the pipeline repo cannot connect to its remote

Comment: I connected back to the office and got back the logs from the pipeline, I'll add them to the Update 1 of my edit, thanks for your help !

Comment: Hi friend, is there any update about this ticket? Does the answer below resolved your question?

Comment: Not yet unfortunately, I explained my latest tests and questions in Update 2, if you could help me, it would be much appreciated.  Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track.

You'll want to update your git command to include "origin" before the branch name and you'll probably want to push the changes after running your pull, or they'll just remain staged locally on the Build Agent.

This should do the trick:

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
      script: |
        git checkout ${{parameters.TargetBranch}}
        git tag ${{parameters.Tag}}
        git push --tags

        git pull origin ${{parameters.SourceBranch}}
        git push
```

Comment: Thank you @Max-Morrow, I feel I'm almost there but still blocked  :(  I wrote my different tests and questions on Update 2 !  Thank you .

Comment: No problem. To resolve the error "fatal: The current branch release has no upstream branch.", you'll want to update **git push** to **git push --set-upstream release**

Comment: Ok thanks, but I don't understand what it does and why it is necessary...  would you be able to explain it ?  I tried from the Github UI to create PR to merge from develop to release and then, release to master yesterday and it worked so the user account does have access!  I'll try the set-upstream now.  Thanks.